# information on GPU socket types

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, processor-socket

I'm looking for information on GPU socket types. In particular I'm looking for mobile GPU socket types. I'm interested in having a mobile GPU re-balled on to my all-in-one motherboard.  the motherboard in question has a socket for a GPU and associated RAM chips,  since of version of this all-in-one computer includes a  dedicated GPU I'm considering buying an MXM card, having the chip removed and RAM modules, and having them placed on my motherboard.

the trouble is that the de facto GPU in question isn't the best available. I don't necessarily mind this but I'm trying to find information on these GPU sockets so that I can make some kind of determination if it's possible to put a better one into the socket.

I also intend to try to find out information about ROMs that limit the types of GPU that can be placed on my motherboard and similar but right now I'm just looking for information about GPU socket types  any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: This is not, in general, possible to do what you are thinking.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Why would it not be possible - it seems reasonably likely to work to me, assuming that the BIOS can support it - which may well be the case if the motherboard has a socked for a GPU.

Comment: Well, for one, socketed GPUs are not generally available.

Comment: My plan currently is to cannibalize an MXM card.

Comment: You might have more success using a Thunderbolt or PCexpress socket and simply adding a regular desktop PCIe graphics card.

Comment: I've not seen a socketed GPU in over a decade, as the core of most GPUs are BGA (Ball Grid Array) which are impossible to hand-solder, and very difficult to solder with DIY reflowing. So I *highly* doubt that cannibalising anything is going to be feasible.

Comment: I'm not going to be doing the re-work myself,  I'm going to send it to a business that does re-works for consumers. There are numerous services that offer re-works of laptops and game consoles,  I'm going to have the re-work done by a professional.

Comment: Please rephrase your request in the form of a question.